# Can't control $('input').click(function()

Tags: jquery, function, input, click

I cannot get my click event to behave. I need it to fire from each every `<input>` in every table row - and only in this table, not in `<input>` elsewhere on the page (not seen in snippet).

```
$('input').click(function() {
```

HOWEVER it does fire from every `<input>` elsewhere on my page (not seen in the snippets).

So I tried to specify it by id.

```
$('#File_Number').click(function() {
```

But this works ONLY on the first table row and only on the first `<input>`.

Each table row is generated from MySQL. Thus there are many occurrences of `id="file_number"`.

Here is the functioning source code: http://jtjohnston.net/clickeventtest/database.php

Ideally, I would like the click event to fire from each of these id, which exist on EVERY row.

```
id="File_Number"
id="File_DateTime"
id="Address"
id="File_Comments"

<tr id="2013-0469">
<td id=""><input id="File_Number" value="2013-0455" type="readonly" size="7"></td>
<td id=""><input id="File_DateTime" value="2013-03-16 03:08:12" type="readonly" size="18"></td>
<td id=""><input id="Address" value="123 Sesame Street" type="readonly" size="20"></td>
<td id=""><input id="File_Comments" value="Something said done entered" type="readonly" size="30"></td>
</tr>
<tr id="2013-0570">
<td id=""><input id="File_Number" value="2013-0965" type="readonly" size="7"></td>
<td id=""><input id="File_DateTime" value="2013-03-17 02:08:14" type="readonly" size="18"></td>
<td id=""><input id="Address" value="123 Baker Street" type="readonly" size="20"></td>
<td id=""><input id="File_Comments" value="Something said done entered" type="readonly" size="30"></td>
</tr>

<script type='text/javascript'>
//$.removeCookie("test");

//$('input').click(function() {
$('#File_Number').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
      alert(id);
//    $.cookie("Row_Id", id, {   expires : 10});
      window.open("something.php","_new");

});

</script>
```

Comment: I very much dislike when people on this forum are mean for the sake of being mean so I hope that you don't take my comments that way. They weren't meant to be hurtful at all but to be constructive. What does get to me a little bit though, is when people ask questions and clearly have little to no understanding of, 1: the question they have asked. 2: the technologies that they are using in their question. what sux is that many people ask questions and get good answers but learn nothing from it. With that said, what really is the point of stackoverflow if not to learn from your failings?

Comment: Huh? Who was mean? What did I miss?
    $('table').on('click', 'input', function(e){
Why is there an "e" in function(e)? I've never seen that before.

Comment: that e is a variable that is an event object that is passed to your function call upon firing the event. it has data attached to it that you can use in the function like client's mouse position or which key was pressed etc.

Answer (score 2):

ID's **need to be unique**, replace all your input ID's with a class instead, then adjust your jQuery accordingly by targeting the class, e.g.

```
$('.File_Number').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
      alert(id);
//    $.cookie("Row_Id", id, {   expires : 10});
      window.open("something.php","_new");

});
```

**Be sure to add an ID to your table too** (in case you use multiple tables on that page).

You could then target it like so:

```
$('#tableID').on('click', 'input', function() {

});
```

Comment: What do you mean by a class?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/ go learn html/css... a class is a way of selecting an element in the DOM so you can alter the style of it in css or (using jquery) access it in javascript

Comment: I use w3schools a lot. But I've never seen a class used like that. I'll go read up on it.

$('table').on('click', 'input', function(e){ Why is there an "e" in function(e)? I've never seen that before.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('#tableID td input').click(function() {
....
```

or delegate the input to table using `on`

```
$('#yourTableID').on('click', 'input', function() {
```

and yes... as always... ID should always be unique... it may work but might get you in trouble later

Comment: this will work assuming that there isn't another table somewhere on the page with inputs in it

Comment: Was it that easy? :) Thanks. But I do have other inputs elsewhere, which are in table cells too. I was hoping for something specific to this table. Can I specify this table by id or something?

Comment: i hope the OP isn't using this response as his answer. Yes this will work in the current scheme but as Bipen and I both mentioned, this will likely get you into trouble down the road if you ever have another table on the page that has inputs in it. To be safe you should be defining your selectors a bit more.

Comment: yes , specify the table with ID and call that selector .. that is the best and fastest solution..updated my answer check it out

Comment: there ya go. much better. Unfortunately, I think that the op's problem lies much deeper than a click statement. It seems that the op really needs to go and spend more time learning the fundamentals of basic html/css/javascript. but upvoted for correct answer

Comment: yes  i think.. seeing the comments..:).. thanks anyways @iAmClownShoe ... and your name :).. cool ;)

Answer (score 1):

Each ID should be unique in a page, so you need to replace the input ids with classes like

```
<tr id="2013-0469">
    <td id=""><input class="File_Number" value="2013-0455" type="readonly" size="7"></td>
    <td id=""><input class="File_DateTime" value="2013-03-16 03:08:12" type="readonly" size="18"></td>
    <td id=""><input class="Address" value="123 Sesame Street" type="readonly" size="20"></td>
    <td id=""><input class="File_Comments" value="Something said done entered" type="readonly" size="30"></td>
</tr>
```

JS

```
$('table').on('click', 'input', function(e){
  var id = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
      alert(id);
//    $.cookie("Row_Id", id, {   expires : 10});
      window.open("something.php","_new");

})
```

Also add an id attribute to the table so that you can identify it easily

```
<table id="my-table">
    <tr>
        <td>.....
```

Then change the script to

```
$('#my-table').on('click', 'input', function(e){
```

Answer (score 0):

Use event delegation:

```
$('#tableid').on('click', 'input', function() {
```

`#tableid` must be the id of your table where you want to listen for its child input clicks.

Answer (score 0):

$(#id_of_your_table tr td input).click(function....)